# How to type cast object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have this expression in Swift?

```swift
if let ddd = internalRepresentation as? [String: Any], 
   let key = key,
   let a = ddd[key]
```

It checkes wether `internalRepresentation`  is object / dictionary, cast it, and then the appripriate value is read.

How can I do this in TypeScipt?

I made this implementation, curious, wether are there any more firendly way to write it?!

```js
if (typeof internalRepresentation === 'object') {
    const ddd = internalRepresentation as Record<string, any>
    const a = ddd[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all just checking the `typeof x === object` isn't enough, since `typeof null` is also `object`, and `typeof []` as well.

What you should do instead is to check if `x` is truthy which will exclude `null` then check the `typeof x === object` and then if it is not an array.

```
if (
  internalRepresentation &&
  typeof internalRepresentation === "object" &&
  !Array.isArray(internalRepresentation)
) {
  const ddd = internalRepresentation;
  const a = ddd[key];
}
```